# Modern ASP.NET forms layout techniques

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, web

We have several internal LOB applications developed in ASP.NET web forms. We have/had always used Html tables to layout data entry forms in these applications.
They have worked fine as they are internal applications and for the most part we control what browsers our users use to access them.
I was wondering what's the latest way to design asp.net data entry forms? we looked at bootstrap but either we will have to use 'their' grids or html tables ( if I am not mistaken).
Just wondering if we are missing out on something.

Thanks

Comment: Broad open-ended "how do I design my website" type questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a broad question but I will try to give you some guidance based on a few basic assumptions.

Tables are a very outdated approach to layout so any attempt to modernise your apps will involve moving away from them.

Bootstrap is an excellent choice for internal apps because it gives you very high standard of presentation for very little work. Yes, things look a little generic but for internal apps that's rarely an issue, compared to on the public web where a site usually needs to define it's own identity. And if you do want to up your game with the visuals, there are loads of good themes to choose from.

Bootstrap has lots of side benefits as well - for example if you use the grid system correctly you get mobile support almost for free.

The good news is that you can bring in Bootstrap and gradually migrate your layouts across. Adding it to a solution doesn't mean you have to remove your tables right away, you can do it on a per-page basis or as part of some other ongoing maintenance process. This hopefully addresses your question of using either grids or tables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we are going forward with Bootstrap.